# In SQL, how to sum numerical values in one column based on string values in another column

Tags: sql

I'd like my procedure to return the total of `AcceptedProducts` by `PlantName`.

Could someone help me to correct my procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAcceptedByCountry @Year INT, @Month INT
AS
    SELECT      CountryCode,
                CountryName,
                REPLACE(SUBSTRING([PlantName], CHARINDEX('-', [PlantName]), LEN([PlantName])), '-', '') AS [PlantName],
                SUM(AcceptedProducts) AS AcceptedProducts 
    FROM        vAcceptedByCountry
    WHERE       YEAR(DateOfManufacture) = @Year AND MONTH(DateOfManufacture) = @Month
    GROUP BY    CountryCode,
                CountryName,
                PlantName,
                AcceptedProducts
    ORDER BY    CountryCode;
GO
```

Thank you for your help.
Kind Regards.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Remove AcceptedProducts from GROUP BY clause and replace  PlantName with REPLACE(SUBSTRING([PlantName], CHARINDEX('-', [PlantName]), LEN([PlantName])), '-', '')

Comment: The question makes no sense.  The question doesn't mention year and month, which are prominent arguments to the stored procedure.  In fact, a stored procedure doesn't even make sense for this.  A user-defined function would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAcceptedByCountry @Year INT, @Month INT
AS
    SELECT      CountryCode,
                CountryName,
                REPLACE(SUBSTRING([PlantName], CHARINDEX('-', [PlantName]), LEN([PlantName])), '-', '') AS [PlantName],
                SUM(AcceptedProducts) AS AcceptedProducts 
    FROM        vAcceptedByCountry
    WHERE       YEAR(DateOfManufacture) = @Year AND MONTH(DateOfManufacture) = @Month
    GROUP BY   1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY    CountryCode;
GO
```

You don't want to group by the aggregate you are trying to calculate.

So, now you are calculating the accepted products per countrycode/countryname/plantname, where the plant name is not the column but the item in your select clause.

Comment: Thank you very much Athanasios. This worked perfectly. I truly appreciate your help. Thank you for the time you kindly spent on this.